# Python - Matplotlib Multi histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to plot several histograms but sometimes bins are larger than others. I cant explain why i obtain that...you can see a plot below, red bins have a great width than others. My code is shown below the figure

[image]

```
import matplotlib as mpl
font = {'family':'serif','serif':'serif','weight':'normal','size':'18'}
mpl.rc('font',**font)
mpl.rc('text',usetex=True)

plt.close()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.15)
num_bins = 50

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(A, num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5, label='Healthy SG')

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(B, num_bins, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, label='Aged SG')

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(C, num_bins, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5, label='Healthy VG')

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(D, num_bins, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5, label='Aged VG')

plt.ylim(0.,10.)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc=2, fontsize= 16)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `bins=num_bins`, each call to `plt.hist` decides where the bin edges should be *independently*. Each call tries to choose bin edges which are appropriate for the data passed. As the data changes, so do the bin edges.

To make the bin widths constant, you'll need to pass the same explicit array of bin edges to each call to `plt.hist`:

```
num_bins = 50
data = np.concatenate([A,B,C,D])
min_data, max_data = data.min(), data.max()
bins = np.linspace(min_data, max_data, num_bins)
plt.hist(A, bins=bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5, label='Healthy SG')
plt.hist(B, bins=bins, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, label='Aged SG')
plt.hist(C, bins=bins, facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5, label='Healthy VG')
plt.hist(D, bins=bins, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5, label='Aged VG')
```